# Por que me sale NaN? Quiero un valor numerico

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy escribiendo código para el carrito de un e-commerce. El calculo del Subtotal, Y el Total, me salen NaN. Me falta algún parseInt ?, escribí demasiados parseInt ?

```
        useEffect(() => {
        
            const nextTotal = userCart
            .map(({item, quantity}) => (parseFloat(item.price)) * (parseFloat(quantity)))
            .reduce(
                (cartTotalPrice, currentItemPrice) => cartTotalPrice + currentItemPrice,
                0
            )   
    setTotal(nextTotal)
    console.log('nextTotal', nextTotal);
}, [userCart])
```

---

```
                {userCart.map((obj) => 
                    (
                        <div key={obj.item.id}>
                            <p>{obj.item.title}</p>
                            <p>{obj.item.price}</p>
                            <p>{obj.quantity}</p>
                            <p>{parseInt(obj.item.price) * parseInt(obj.quantity)}</p>
                            <button
```

Estos dos códigos no son de la misma cosa, el primero es del total, y el segundo, subTotal

Si tienen mas dudas del codigo, aca esta mi link a GitHub: https://github.com/LautaroLamalfa/ubiquitous-doodle.git

Comment: Podrias imprimir item.price y quantity por separado para ver que tienen esas variables?

Comment: No se si te entendí bien la pregunta... pero en el segundo están impresos como obj.item.price y obj.quantity y esos se ven los numeros

Comment: Y esos numeros, se ven con comas o con puntos?

Comment: ... nooo, no salen comas y puntos

Comment: habra algun numero que esta mal? habria que ver algun ejemplo....

Comment: que escribí parseInt en uno y no en otro?? Me fijare, aca tenes el codigo para si queres

Comment: antes de hacer operaciones matematicas; debes controlar que los datos que estas usando sean numero enteros o flotanto, te sugiero que hagas un control de errores y muestres en consola cuando uno de estos datos no cumple... incluso hasta suele dar problemas cuando si querer divides entre 0 o divides un 0.

Comment: El problema debe estar en tu destructuring que haces en el parámetro del map: item.price seguramente es un numero, pero por si las dudas verifica que tu quantity también lo sea.... cualquier operación(suma, resta, multiplicación o división) entre un numero y un undefined te va dar como resultado un NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema parece ser el valor `string` de `price`, tiene un símbolo `Dollar/peso` antes del precio:

```
    //extracto tomado del archivo src/data/
    {
      "id": "1", 
      "title": "Sofa", 
      "description": "Marron", 
      "stock": "10 unidades",
      "price": "$60",
      "categoryId": "Ambiente"
    },
```

El método [`parseFloat`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) transforma un número de `string` a `float`, pero en este caso el símbolo `Dollar/peso` no permite dicha transformación, obteniendo `NaN` como resultado.

> parseFloat: If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat() returns NaN

```js
let price = "$200";
let toFloat = parseFloat(price);
console.log(toFloat);
```

Una forma de arreglar el problema sería transformando `price` con el método [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```js
let price = "$200";
let toFloat = parseFloat(price.replace("$",""));
console.log(toFloat);
```

Puede quedar así:

```
const nextTotal = userCart
            .map(({item, quantity}) => (parseFloat(item.price.replace("$",""))) * (parseFloat(quantity)))
            .reduce(
                (cartTotalPrice, currentItemPrice) => cartTotalPrice + currentItemPrice,
                0
            );
```

La misma modificación aplica para `subTotal`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: También es buena idea almacenar el precio sin símbolo.